# Datatable Jquery-- Is it possible to create the table in the server side and send just the table as an output in datatable jquery

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

Is it possible to send formatted t body(server side with tr and TD) from ctp file to an Ajax call. Because data table creates the tr TD by default. But I want to create the tr and td in the server side and send the output. I am using PHP in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly...

```
<?php
// testfile.php
$param = $_GET['param1'];

$table = '<table id="my_table">';

switch($param1)
{
 case 1:     
  for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
   $table .= '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>SOME TEXT</td></tr>';
 break;


 case 2:     
  for($i=100;$i<=105;$i++)
   $table .= '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>ANOTHER TEXT</td></tr>';
 break;
}
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;

?>
```

Now call it, using ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: testfile.php,
  cache: false,
  async: false,
  data : 'param1='+ $('#some_hidden_field_value').val(),
  success:function(obj){
    $('#div_with_table').html(obj);
  }
});
```

And run the jquery datatable plugin :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#my_table').dataTable();
});
```